# Why mark something final in Swift except for architectural considerations?

Tags: swift

Except for obvious reasons, such as if by design I do not want certain method, or property, or whatever to be overridden down the inheritance tree, are there other reasons to mark things `final` in Swift?

For example, are there performance considerations?  I recall reading somewhere on SO answers that suggest something along the line.

Comment: To prevent things from being overridden?

Comment: @nhgrif, of course.  The question is whether there are any other reasons worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Is it necessary for their to be non-obvious reasons?  Except for obvious reasons, such as if I need to represent things like words, is there any reason I should mark a variable as a string?

Comment: @EricD., thanks a lot.  The article even addresses the next question I had in mind, which is whether marking things `private` can affect performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Apple's Swift blog: [Increasing Performance by Reducing Dynamic Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27)

> Swift allows a class to override methods and properties declared in its superclasses. This means that the program has to determine at runtime which method or property is being referred to and then perform an indirect call or indirect access. This technique, called dynamic dispatch, increases language expressivity at the cost of a constant amount of runtime overhead for each indirect usage.

Using `final` is one of several ways to improve performance by eliminating such dynamism:

> The "final" keyword is a restriction on a class, method, or property that indicates that the declaration cannot be overridden. This allows the compiler to safely elide dynamic dispatch indirection.

Comment: It's a pity that final is not default - and that methods are not private by default :)

Comment: Hardly. Why disable two key features of an object-oriented language and force the user to turn them on explicitly?